# Como se corrigen los errores: the attribute name is invalid: ‘ ‘ y el Xcode no creó los “profiles” para mi App

Tags: xcode

Intento ejecutar mi aplicación en un dispositivo iPhone 6 Plus (12.5.4), usando una cuenta de no pago. Se producen 2 errores en “Signing & Capabilities” > Status: 1. An attribute in the provided entity has invalid value (the attribute ‘name’ is invalid: ‘’) y 2. Xcode (versión 12.5.1) “couldn’t find any iOS App Development provisioning profile matching ...” No tengo idea cómo corregir esos errores.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Creaste los certificados y perfiles de development con la cuenta de apple?

Comment: Escogí la opción que Xcode cree y actualice los perfiles y certificados, pero no lo hace !!

Comment: Hay un atributo que está mal en el certificado. Puedes agregar como tienes los certificados e identificadores?

Comment: Para el segundo error debes crear el perfil en la página de [Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/)

Comment: Agregué imagen del certificado. Para crear el perfil debería prescindir de Xcode como encargado de gestionar certificados y perfil, y asumir yo toda la responsabilidad procediendo manualmente ?

Comment: Xcode genera y soluciona ese tipo de errores pero es extraño el error que te marca acerca de un atributo. Veo que tienes el certificado pero te falta el perfil con ese `bundle identifier`, lo tienes creado?

Comment: Trata usando com.william.recignisingshapes